# Filling a dataframe with high speed

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a pandas Series where each cells is a dictionary :

```
data.individus.head(5)
Out[25]: 
0    [{'dateDeNaissance': 1954-09-14 00:00:00, 'enc...
1    [{'dateDeNaissance': 1984-09-14 00:00:00, 'enc...
2    [{'enceinte': False, 'dateDeNaissance': 1981-0...
3    [{'dateDeNaissance': 1989-09-14 00:00:00, 'enc...
4    [{'enceinte': False, 'dateDeNaissance': 1989-0...
Name: individus, dtype: object
```

I would like to construct a pandas Dataframe using each dictionnary, like so :

```
t_individus.ix[:, ['dateDeNaissance', 'enceinte']].head()
Out[14]: 
       dateDeNaissance enceinte
0  1954-09-14 00:00:00    False
1  1984-09-14 00:00:00    False
2  1981-09-14 00:00:00    False
3  1989-09-14 00:00:00    False
4  1989-09-14 00:00:00    False
```

Note that I have many more keys (~50) but i'm showing 2 for the example.

I tried 2 different ways but I'm not entirely satisfied with the processing speed :

**1/ Concatening**

```
serie = data.foo  #  110199 lines
keys = get_all_possible_keys(serie)  # 48 keys (process time: 0.8s)
table = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(keys))

for i in serie:
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(i.items()))
    df = df.transpose()
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0))
    table = pd.concat([table, df], axis=0)
```

It starts fast and then slowly decrease while `table` gets bigger. Overall process takes around 1 hours.

**2/ Pre-allocate memory and filling row by row**

```
serie = data.foo
keys = get_all_possible_keys(serie)
len_serie = len(serie)
# -- Pre-allocate memory by declaring size
table = pd.DataFrame(np.nan,
                     index=range(0, len_serie),
                     columns=list(keys))
# -- Fill row by row
k = 0
for i in serie:
    table.loc[k] = pd.Series(i[0])
    k += 1
```

Processing time depends on `table`'s size. It's much faster with a subset (~10k lines) and gets incredibly slower with the full dataset (110k lines).

2 Questions :

1. Why method 2 gets so slow when `table` is big (much slower than method 1) while its only filling empty rows ?
2. Any ideas on how I could speed-up the process ?

Comment: Probably the issue here is that it doesn't know what the dtypes are upfront when you construct your dataframe like this for method 2 so your df will have a mixed dtype until you fully fill the df, if you know the dtypes can you try passing these in the constructor, saying that it seems that you can't pass mixed dtypes. One method would be to set all rows to the same value as the first entry and then update row by row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost the same idea as @James's, but in your case you have a series of lists of dicts, which you want to convert to list of dicts or to series of dicts first:

```
In [12]: s
Out[12]:
0    [{'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb', 'c': 'ccc'}]
1       [{'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1'}]
dtype: object

In [13]: pd.DataFrame(s.sum())
Out[13]:
     a    b    c
0  aaa  bbb  ccc
1   a1   b1   c1

In [14]: s.sum()
Out[14]: [{'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb', 'c': 'ccc'}, {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1'}]
```

using `.tolist()`:

```
In [15]: pd.DataFrame(s.tolist())
Out[15]:
                                      0
0  {'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb', 'c': 'ccc'}
1     {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1'}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found in the past that it is surprisingly quick to build a dataframe from a list of dicts. My simple suggestion would be to try,

```
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data.foo.tolist())
```

Comment: i think in this case it should be `pd.DataFrame(data.individus.sum())`